# Picasso image loading

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to load images from camera path in gridview with the help of Picasso 2.5.2

storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150822_133220.jpg
here is the path.

Also I tried the given solution for the issue in Github repo of picasso. But it doesn't solve my problem.

I tried with Transformation of picasso, but images not getting load from camera path.

I tried this

```
File imageFile = new File(data.path);
Picasso.with(mContext)
  .load(imageFile)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.default_error)
  .error(R.drawable.default_error)
  .resize(mItemSize, mItemSize)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(image);
```

Comment: Can you please show the code and if there is an error in the logcat?

Comment: @Miriana Itani : Question updated. Also tried with the uri, stringpath, and both with "file:///" as prefix, but nor working. I stuck on it.

Comment: What is phone are you using with what software?

Comment: Actually phone doesn't matter here. I tried with with Samsung SM-G355H (4.4.2) , HTC Desire 816G(4.4.2), Samsung S3(4.2).

Comment: I was just checking if it a lollipop thing. I know this is a stupid but you have all the permissions right? I also want you try to load a url. Then we could start narrowing the problem down.

Comment: A dev also has the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270090/picasso-library-does-not-load-images-from-sd-card-on-adroid

Comment: is your path exactly `storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150822_133220.jpg`?

Comment: yes. It is the path. I have checked that on also confirm with 
 `File file = new File(filePath);
  if(file.exists())`

Comment: Does it give you any errors if you pass it a callback as the second parameter to `.into()` (as done at the other Picasso question you linked)?

Comment: No. It doesn't give me any error. It is directly showing the ErrorPlaceholder

Comment: can you try to load the image with a different library like fresco? it can give some clarity as to if the problem is in picasso or some other component.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a url into the `load()` method.

```
File imageFile = new File(data.path);

 try{
        String url = imageFile.toURI().toURL().toString(); 
        Picasso.with(mContext)
               .load(url)
               .placeholder(R.drawable.default_error)
               .error(R.drawable.default_error)
               .resize(mItemSize, mItemSize)
               .centerCrop()
               .into(image);   
    }catch (MalformedURLException exeption){
        exeption.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hardcoded paths to access sd card content -- they're not universal across devices.

Use `.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` and the proper two-parameter `File` constructor instead:

```
File f = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
        "Camera/IMG_20150822_133220.jpg");
Picasso.with(mContext).load(f)./* ..;
```

**UPD** Oh actually, apart from that, they have [an open bug](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1069) that looks related, someone there says they worked around the issue using absolute path, so try

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(data.path).getAbsolutePath())...
```

Comment: It's not hard coded. I gave you the path which I'm getting while debugging.

Comment: Found something, take a look at the update in my answer

Comment: Barstov . Sorry, with Absolutepath it is still not working.

Comment: Hm. Ok, then I'm all out of suggestions. At least go and your comment or a simple *+1* to the bug on github I linked -- that'll make it draw developer's attention faster.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem now and this is how I solved it. I'm trying to take a screenshot of my phone's screen and then I saved it down as a jpg file in this filepath:

```
filepath: /data/data/com.example.simon.myapp/app_report/report.jpg
```

However, Picasso was not loading this at all - it was just giving me a blank screen.

So then when I took the screenshot, I decided to remove the .jpg from the filename so that the filepath resembles this:

```
filepath: /data/data/com.example.simon.myapp/app_report/report
```

I then used the following code to access and display my screenshot with no further problems.

```
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    File directory = cw.getDir("report", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    file = new File(directory, "/report");
    Log.e("filepath", file.getPath());
    Picasso.with(context).load(file).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(screenshot);
```

I know that you will need to get the jpg file extension at some future stage, so if you need to get the "report.jpg", simply rename the file using this method:

[android, How to rename a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424997/android-how-to-rename-a-file)

```
private boolean rename(File from, File to) {
    return from.getParentFile().exists() && from.exists() && from.renameTo(to);
}
```